# How do you send websocket data to connected clients using C++ Seasocks?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, websocket

I am using the Seasocks C++ library in order to add websocket functionality to an existing project. How do I initiate the sending of data to connected clients from the C++ code?

My code so far is as follows:

```
// .....
#include "seasocks/PrintfLogger.h"
#include "seasocks/Server.h"
#include "seasocks/WebSocket.h"
#include <thread>

using namespace seasocks;

namespace {
    struct Handler : WebSocket::Handler {
        std::set<WebSocket*> _cons;
        void onConnect(WebSocket* con) override {
            _cons.insert(con);
            send("Connected");
        }
        void onDisconnect(WebSocket* con) override {
            _cons.erase(con);
            send("Disconnected");
        }
        void onData(WebSocket* con, const char* data) override {
            send(data);
        }
        void send(const std::string& msg) {
            for (auto* con : _cons) {
                con->send(msg);
            }
        }
    };
}
SmartConfig::SmartConfig(StorageContainer container, QObject *parent) : 
        QObject(parent),
        _storage(container),
        _webserver(NULL),
        _server(std::make_shared<PrintfLogger>())
{

    std::thread seasocksThread([&] {
        _server.addWebSocketHandler("/Socket", std::make_shared<Handler>(), true);
        _server.startListening(9090);
        _server.loop();
    });
    seasocksThread.detach();

    // .....
}
```

At this stage I can connect a client to the server and send data to it. It responds with whatever was sent, which is fine for now, but how do I initiate the sending of data to connected clients in various parts of the code or in other classes? I believe that I should be using something like:

```
seasocks::Server().execute({
    send("Some data to send.");
});
```

This doesn't work however. I get the following error:

`no instance of constructor "seasocks::Server::Server" matches the argument list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is me restating the [quick tutorial](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/seasocks/wiki/Seasocks-quick-tutorial), but hopefully in a clearer way.

The function `execute()` is a method on the `server` object, and it accepts a "function to call" on the correct thread. Your example is trying to construct a new `Server`, then call its `execute` method with an initializer list (I think!).

To do useful work, though, you need to know which clients to send messages to. The server doesn't keep track of that: it delegates that responsibility to the individual `Handler`s. Think of the `Handler` as like a single web page handler: a website doesn't have "clients" but each page does (the clients that are viewing it)

You'll need to make a Handler for the page you want (e.g. the `ChatHandler` in the tutorial). That handler will remember the list of clients attached to it:

```cpp
struct ChatHandler : WebSocket::Handler {
  set<WebSocket *> connections;
  void onConnect(WebSocket *socket) override 
    { connections.insert(socket); }
  void onData(WebSocket *, const char *data) override 
    { for (auto c : connections) c->send(data); }
  void onDisconnect(WebSocket *socket) override 
    { connections.erase(socket); }
};

// I'd never use globals normally but for simplicity:
std::shared_ptr<ChatHandler> chatHandler;
Server server(make_shared<PrintfLogger>());

void chat() {
  chatHandler = make_shared<ChatHandler>();
  server.addWebSocketHandler("/chat", chatHandler);
  server.serve("web", 9090);
}
```

In this example the chat client simply echoes the data it receives to all connected clients. As the `onData` method is called from the Seasocks thread, no `execute()` shenanigans is needed.

If one wanted to send a message to all connected clients from another thread, one might use code like this:

```cpp
void sendToAll(const char *data) {
  server.execute([] {
    for (auto c : chatHandler->connections) c->send(data);
  });
}
```

This creates an anonymous function (a lambda) which will reach into the chat handler and call "send" on each of its clients. It then passes this lambda to `server.execute()` -- this will ensure the lambda is executed on the correct thread.

Specifically in your case I'd suggest:

- Keeping hold of the `Handler` shared_ptr you create in the `SmartConfig` structure. Make `shared_ptr<Handler>` member variable `(_handler`), construct it and then also pass it into `addWebSocketHandler`.
- When you want to send to all connections, call `_server.execute([this, msg]{ _handler.send(msg);});`

I hope that helps a little: it's not that clear, and C++ syntax isn't the easiest.

Comment: Thanks very much for you detailed answer Matt. I have been able to implement what you have suggested and it working perfectly.